# How do I set the SESSION variable in a foreach loop for each particular data

Tags: php, arrays, session, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop that outputs items held in an array. This works great, but I want to store a few things per EACH item in the session variables so that information is available elsewhere. I am trying to create session variables inside the `foreach` loop, but of course the variables need to have different data every time it loops through a different item.

Suppose I have product data: `Name`, `Image`, `Price` and a button with a link. In this case the button link will be stored in a session variable inside the `foreach` loop because this link should be use elsewhere. When I click on the button that particular link for that particular product is stored in the session variable. When I redirect from one page to another I use that link, which is in a session variable using the session concept.

However, when I redirect from one page to another and echo the session variable (product link), it only echos the last value (last product link). Suppose I have five items and they have five different product links. When the session variable is echoed on redirection, the PHP page will only take the last value of the `foreach` loop. Instead it takes that particular product links.

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: You really need to show your code and enumerate your inputs and what you're getting out, along with what you expect to get out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SESSION can be of any proper php type, array, for example.
So you just have to fill an array with your data, and set `$_SESSION['data'] = $array;`. That's all. In any consequent request for that user the data will be there and accessible just like $_POST, $_GET, etc.

Each time you set that variable - previous values will be lost, if you don't do anything to save them elsewhere.